# Concatenate hard coded value to ViewModel property via XAML?

Tags: wpf, label

I have a simple Label in WPF as under:-

```
<Label  Content="{Binding MyViewModel.SomeValue,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
<Label  Canvas.Top="26" Canvas.Left="253" Content="{Binding "Hardcoded String"+CurrentRec.Current_Vendor_Purchase_Record.TaxName,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

and this:

```
<Label  Canvas.Top="26" Canvas.Left="253" Content="Hard Coded String Value"+ "{Binding CurrentRec.Current_Vendor_Purchase_Record.TaxName,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

How can i concatenate some hard coded value to MyViewModel.SomeValue from XAML side?I mean i can always do it from code-behind,but just wanted to know how to add a hard coded value to a ViewModel property in XAML DataBinding?
I know it shouldn't be difficuilt,but plz discount me as a beginner :-).

Comment: Just because I'm interested: Why do you want to do this? Seems a bit like an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You could use a `ValueConverter` that always concatenates your string, but tbh, i'd rather just add an extra label with the text in it

Comment: Then also use a TextBlock instead of a Label to display text.

Comment: @Mighty Badaboom:Actually i have a drop down list which displays various Tax codes and there selecteditem's Tax_Percentage property is shown in Label.So i just wanted it to appear like 4.5%,ie the '%' sign needs to be hardcoded to whatever is the value from DataBinding.

Comment: You could use an `IValueConverter`and convert the text like you want. You could use `string.Format`in your xaml as well but I think it's just working with `TextBlock` and not with `Label`. That's why I would recommend the `IValueConverter`.

Comment: @Timothy:Yeah that is what i am currently doing,but was wondering whether if there was a better way of somehow adding the hardcoded value in the XAMl itself.

Comment: @Clemens:Even if i use a TextBox,or TextBlock instead of Label,how does it help?i mean how can i add a literal string to TextBox using pure XAML only?

Comment: Did you see the answer?

Comment: @Clemens:yes,but initially could not understand why you suggested me to go in for a TextBlock untill i saw till the end..:-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two different `Run` elements:

```
<Label Canvas.Top="26" Canvas.Left="253">
    <Label.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Hardcoded String" /><Run Text="{Binding CurrentRec.Current_Vendor_Purchase_Record.TaxName, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

You don't event need to use a `Label` element:

```
<TextBlock Canvas.Top="26" Canvas.Left="253">
    <Run>Hardcoded String</Run><Run Text="{Binding CurrentRec.Current_Vendor_Purchase_Record.TaxName, Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```

This will *display* the concatenated values in the view.

Comment: tx mms8.Your answer was the closest.No code behind,and still got the literal added.Thanks